# ViewPager, Fragment, When activity resumes after inactivity GridView disappears

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager

Does anyone have an answer for this. I've looked thru all my code, but can't figure it out? Is there any onResume etc. I've forgotten?
I use a custom GridViewAdapter
Thanks

UPDATE:

```
public static void bindGridView(final Activity context) {
    if (mGridView == null) {
        mGridView = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_view_n1);
    }
    mFavortieAdapter = new GridViewInfo(context,FavoriteTextList, FavoriteDrawableList, FavoriteID);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mFavortieAdapter);
    mGridView.setSelection(0);

    // Implement On Item click listener
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            String db_int = FavoriteIntent.get(position);
            getApplicationName(db_int, context);
        }
    });
}
```

This gets called in the onCreate.

Comment: Post how you are saving/rebuilding your Gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DeeV got me in the right direction. I looked into how the GridView was saving/rebuilding and apparently the gridView is not null after resume and is therefor not called again.

Removed the if statements from this line:

```
if (mGridView == null) {
    mGridView = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_view_n1);
}
```

Thanks DeeV